# C/C++ compiler generating obfuscated code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, obfuscation

Is there any known C/C++ compiler generating obfuscated/noised code?
Or maybe any patch for open-source C/C++ compiler like GCC?

Comment: `-O3` is really hard to decipher

Comment: Well, the machine code the C and C++ compilers produce is pretty obfuscated already. Come to think of it, some C and C++ code I've seen is already pretty obfuscated... :-P

Comment: Obfuscated ... machine code? Or are you talking about *compiling* obfuscated *source*? May I ask why do you need this?

Comment: Yes, obfuscated machine code, against reverse engineering. Why compiler cannot generate it right in back-end?

Comment: Maybe because nobody needed it? Compilers always were about producing *efficient* code. Again, what is the problem such obfuscation would solve?

Comment: But people still need .NET, Java obfuscators... guess why?

Comment: Hmm ... .NET and Java byte-code are much higher level then any real assembler, so are much easier to map back to source constructs. I find it kind of silly - like distributing a shell script but wanting it to be "unreadable".

Comment: http://hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml

Comment: Do you have any idea how useful Hex Rays actually is? While it can produce technically-valid C/C++ code, it's often less readable than the assembly it was created from. You can't really obfuscate machine code to the point where it can't be disassembled but is still usable by the machine. In addition, you can never obfuscate anything to the point where people can't reverse it if they try, they can just use a debugger (if I remember correctly, IDA Pro includes Hex Rays). As Nikolai said, it will likely be unnecessarily slow and you won't actually stop anyone from reverse engineering it.

Comment: Yes, people can reverse engineer your binary. So? If they want it really bad, they'd be able to reverse your obfuscation too. When that fails, they'll send a couple of heavy-weight gorillas to your house and you'll tell them all the hidden truth. There is no point here. If it's a secret - keep it to yourself. If you give it to somebody else - it's not a secret anymore.

Comment: Can I just get the answer to my question about existence of such thing?

Comment: Yes, there is obfuscator-llvm: https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki
However, the project seems unmaintained.

Answer (score 4):

You can obfuscate assembler with http://www.pelock.com/products/obfuscator . You can probably compile to assembler (in this case MASM style) and then obfuscate it.

**Edit:** Using many virtual functions/indirection and/or an interpreter (i.e. create your own mini-bytecode for certain steps of your processing) as part of your code results, in my experience, in quite unreverseable code.

Comment: *"`You can probably compile to assembler (in this case MASM style).`"* any tutorial about it?

Answer (score 2):

Any compiler thats able to generate a pseudo random-esque numbers(via `__COUNTER__`) and can inject bytes into an inline assembly stream (via `__emit`) can perform inline code obfuscation, its nothing like what external packers and obfuscaters do, which can be an advantageous. The 'strenght' relies mostly on how much metaprogramming you put into it, but obviously you'd never be able to say encrypt IAT's etc.

Comment: any example of that?

Comment: @Zibri http://blog.sevagas.com/?Fun-combining-anti-debugging-and then all you need to do is things `__emit __COUNTER__` instead of fixed instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach may be to run the executable inside a protected VM environment. [ZProtect](http://www.peguard.com/solutions/software-protection/) -- a product I have have neither used nor endorse, but rather found with an "I'm feeling luck Google" -- claims to provide multiple levels of code protection (VM, encryption, obfuscation, etc).

If someone really, really wants to know how you did something, they'll find out -- if it's IP theft, then hire a good lawyer. If it's crypto, then use a proven industry approach. And if it's something DRM, well, that's a fight moving to hardware (and root kits) anyway.

Comment: DRM is a fight moving to the stupid. The pirates will win, eventually. Same with any other IP, as soon as it leaves your possession, it's only a matter of time till someone takes it fully out of your control.

Comment: this is not I think the asnwer